# Injecting a Map into a costructor using annotations

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations

Can someone please tell me how I can wire the following constructor with a Map object without using XML, and just using annotations? Is it possible?

```
public class MyClass {
...
    public MyClass (final Map<String, SomeBean> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
...
}
```

Current XML I would like to get rid of:

```
<bean id="mybean" class="my.package.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg>
        <util:map>
            <entry key="KEY1" value-ref="ref-bean1" />
            <entry key="KEY2" value-ref="ref-bean2" />
        </util:map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="ref-bean1" class="my.package.SomeBean">... </bean>

<bean id="ref-bean2" class="my.package.SomeBean">... </bean>
```

Comment: Would it be OK to use [`@Configuration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)? This solution would only move the XML config to Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Spring config is configured for annotation configuration, you should be able to eliminate the `myBean` declaration by just marking the constructor of `MyClass` as `@Autowired`.

```
public class MyClass {
...
    @Autowired
    public MyClass (final Map<String, SomeBean> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
...
}
```

Spring will attempt to wire the `MyClass` constructor using a `Map` of `SomeBean` instances keyed by bean name.

As there are separate instances of `SomeBean` configured (presumably with their own state), you'll need to leave these in the XML.

```
<bean id="KEY1" class="my.package.SomeBean">... </bean>

<bean id="KEY2" class="my.package.SomeBean">... </bean>
```

Alternatively, as LaurentG says, there's always `@Configuration`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I actually ended up autowiring the 2 beans as members of MyClass and then created the map in a getMap() method. Ideally, I would have liked to create this map in the default constructor of MyClass, but found that the 2 beans were not wired in at that point yet (they were null).